# Does Firebase REST streaming support ordering and filtering child nodes?

Tags: firebase

I would like to stream changes to a Firebase location, but filter the results based on a query to some index, like so:

```
curl -i -L -H "Accept: text/event-stream" https://mydata.firebaseio.com/path.json?'orderBy="myIndexedField"&equalTo="desiredValue"'
```

What I observe is that Firebase appears to ignore my query and proceeds to stream all changes to that location whether they match the query or not. Is there any way to do this, other than writing code to perform my own client-side filtering?

EDIT

Frank's answer below shows that Firebase does indeed honor your query parameters. The problem I'm having still persists, and I simply misconstrued what was going on, as the situation turns out to be a little more complicated. I've reproduced my issue in Frank's Firebase, which he was kind enough to supply as a live example for this question.

Here are the steps to reproduce my issue:

Start a streaming query with the constraint type == 1:

```
$ curl -i -L -H "Accept: text/event-stream" 'https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/29265457/.json?print=pretty&orderBy="type"&equalTo=1'
```

In a separate terminal, post a new item with type==1:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"type": 1}' https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/29265457/.json
{"name":"-JlY1nAmymCKw5lvLvMe"}
```

This object pops up in my ongoing curl stream as expected, since it matches the query of type==1:

```
event: patch
data: {"path":"/","data":{"-JlY1nAmymCKw5lvLvMe":{"type":1}}}
```

Now, here's the part I misinterpreted as Firebase ignoring queries. If I PUT that resource I just POSTed and change it to type==0, it still shows up in my stream! To perform the PUT:

```
$ curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"type": 0}' https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/29265457/-JlY1nAmymCKw5lvLvMe.json
```

And here's what I see pop up in my ongoing stream curl:

```
event: patch
data: {"path":"/","data":{"-JlY1nAmymCKw5lvLvMe":{"type":0}}}
```

If I PUT "type" to 0 again, it no longer shows up in my curl stream terminal. If I PUT type to 1, then it does pop up in my curl stream (expected). It's the transition from 1->0 where I get the unexpected event.

Also, using PATCH instead of PUT to modify "type" appears to result in the same behavior in the curl stream.

I think it's natural to expect that when I change a value to NOT match my query anymore, I wouldn't see it in my stream. However, it looks like perhaps the query is being matched before the value is edited, or something along those lines... I have no idea how this is implemented on the Firebase end.

So I guess the new question is: How can I avoid seeing changed values that don't match my query in the REST stream?

Comment: I think the patch might be showing up because at that point the node *disappears* from the query. So in a similar vein to how you'd get a child_removed event with the regular SDKs.

Comment: If that's the case, it would be helpful if this behavior was documented in the REST streaming docs.

Comment: Fair enough. I added it as a task to improve the documentation on REST streaming and queries. But is it clear for the moment why you are getting the `PATCH` when the node disappears from your "query" (I prefer to think of it as a "data window")?

Comment: If that's how it was designed to behave, then it's clear that this is what I should expect, and my client code should handle these extra events accordingly. Speaking for myself, however, it's not clear _why_ it's designed this way. In order to see a child_removed event, I would need to subscribe to it in the JS binding via `firebaseRef.on("child_removed", ...)`. If I don't ask to see the events, then I don't get them. In the case of the REST API stream, my opinion of the situation is that I'm seeing events I didn't ask for, and that do not match my query.

Comment: My particular problem, now that I am aware of the behavior, is solved by having written client-side filtering code that re-checks the query logic against the event's data. Your answer does correctly address the original question, so I'll mark it as answered. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that could be wrong here:

1. you didn't define an index on `myIndexedField`
2. your URL is quoted incorrectly

Ad 1) When you access Firebase through the (JavaScript/iOS/Java) libraries, it will fall back to client-side ordering and filtering if you're ordering/filtering data that is not indexed. Given that the REST API doesn't come with a client-library, it cannot perform such a fallback and it will simply return the data unordered/unfiltered.

Ad 2) you need to put your single quotes around the *entire* URL, not just the query string. An example curl that works for me:

```
curl -i -L -H "Accept: text/event-stream" 'https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/29265457/.json?orderBy="type"&equalTo=0'
```

I push data to it with this JavaScript snippet:

```
new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/29265457/').push({ type: 0 });
```

And it shows up in the curl window; or it doesn't if I set type to 1.

Comment: I don't think the quotes are an issue, as unix shells allow you to concatenate strings by placing them one after another. Here's an illustrative example: `VAR=variable echo unquoted"doublequoted"'singlequoted'unquoted$VAR$VAR"indoublequotes$VAR" 'var name not value = $VAR'`

Comment: I do agree that the query in the streaming request to your sample firebase works as I'd expect. I can filter the stream data on type==1 via my curl command, and via my golang binding. I think my problem lies in my specific query, or in my security rules. I do have the field I'm filtering indexed. Now that I'm sure this feature works within Firebase, I'll double down on my stuff to figure out what's wrong... thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Did you *try* moving the quotes. You might be surprised: it made the entire difference between working and non-working on my bash environment.

Comment: Yes, I did try, and that was not the solution. I've better wrapped my head around what's happening on my end, and I've found that the situation is a little more complicated. I've reproduced the issue with your Firebase as well. I will edit the question, as this is a little long to explain in the comments.